# Where is this render method defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm going along this guide trying to get started with Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html, I'm at this point in the tutorial where we have the following controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
      render text: params[:post].inspect
  end
end
```

Where are these `render` method and `params` hash defined? what does this hash contain? I'm trying to search for `ApplicationController` in the API but I only find `ActionController`, which supposedly `ApplicationController` inherits from, still I can't seem to find the method or hash in the documentation, what am I missing here? thanks in advance for any comment or help.

Comment: The `params` hash contains the request parameters and a few Rails-specific values. Consider using a tool like "pry" to look at stuff like that

Answer (score 2):

The relevant gem you want to look for is actionpack. Using bundler you can easily find or open the directory where this gem is installed:

```
bundle show actionpack
bundle open actionpack
```

Once you've open the actionpack gem in an editor that lets you do a project search, or grepped the directory where actionpack is installed, search for `def params` and `def render` and it will show you the file and line where these methods are defined. `render` is in `lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb` line 95, and `params` is in `lib/action_controller/metal.rb` line 141.

Read the source Luke.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-render
You can pres source code and see the code of the method.